# How do I determine the level and XP reward of mobs in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a little lost on this one - how can I determine what level the mobs are that I'm fighting, and additionally, how can I see the XP reward from killing in each one?

I MIGHT be able to determine this by watching the XP bar grow, but that's not very useful or easy. And I still cannot determine the level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to access this. I did a quick search hoping that there'd be results on some type of combat log (similar to WOW, which shows stats on damage, status change, and XP) But from my search, I didn't see anything come up. A combat log may be a feature we see in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of determining a monster's level as of now. If you want to know the XP from killing a monster, you'll have to kill one, and then see the difference in experience points. This value will change when you level up, however.

Comment: Even that is dubious, since level difference between the hero and the monster affects the XP reward, and since there's no way of knowing the level...

Comment: @Oak True. I'll include that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Monster level can be determined by searching [offline](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster) [databases](http://d3db.com/npc#1-1-0) for the monsters name you are interested in.  When using d3db.com, I highly recommend the Firefox "Firebug" plug in for searching of the link text, since the names tend to be non-sensical (but the link text makes sense).

Do note that monster level depends on difficulty level, so you'll see 4 levels listed for each monster (corresponding to the 4 difficulty levels).

Comment: I think that's a good answer.