# Do all monsters of a given level reward the same XP?

Tags: diablo-iii

At the moment there is no way to conclusively determine a monster's level other than the XP rewarded from killing it, relative to your player's level according to [How do I determine the level and XP reward of mobs in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66886/how-do-i-determine-the-level-and-xp-reward-of-mobs-in-diablo-iii).

However, if you do determine a monster's level and kill it, does it reward the same XP as any other monster the same level?  Is the amount of XP affected by type, e.g. ghoul vs carrion bat vs grotesque?  Is the amount of XP affected by monster status, e.g. normal monster vs champion vs unique/miniboss vs boss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, but there are some significant caveats.**

1. Many pieces of gear affect how much experience you get from monsters.  When comparing with others, you should remove all such gear.
2. There is still some debate about grouping with higher level heroes.  I'll have more updates on that, in that question.
3. A monsters level depends on the difficulty level.
4. Remember that when your level changes (typically up), monster experience scales down.

There is a very helpful table [here](http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/diablo-3-experience-points-explained.html) which lists the experience scaling for your level compared to a given monsters level.  It is also untrue that you can't [determine](http://d3db.com/npc#1-1-0) [the level](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster) of a monster - but I don't think there is a way to determine it *in game*.  I've also been taking measurements for other questions in various parties, and I've found the output to be consistent with the conclusion that monsters of the same level always award the same amount of experience.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be true anymore.  As of [Patch 1.08](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/9647272/patch-108-now-live-5-7-2013#monsters), some monsters have had their experience and loot reduced to better match their hit points.  Blizzard is not saying that these monsters have been reduced in level, just in experience and loot.

The other possibility is that experience and loot are still derived from monster level but the monster levels listed at [db3b.com](http://d3db.com/npc#1-1-0) and [d3lexicon.com](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster) are now incorrect.  Look at [Tormented Stingers](http://d3db.com/npc/i/tormented-stinger) ([d3lexicon.com](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/tormented-stinger)) for an example of a monster whose experience and loot have been nerfed even though they still show as level 63 in Inferno.

I didn't edit the previous answer because the Patch 1.08 changes aren't clearly defined enough.  We're forced to speculate a bit as to the exact change.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment on the previous answer.