# How can I tell what level enemies are?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the level and XP reward of mobs in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66886/how-do-i-determine-the-level-and-xp-reward-of-mobs-in-diablo-iii)

My armor skill tells me it reduces damage from same-level enemies by X%, however how do I know if I'm fighting same-level enemies or not?