# How do I know what levels enemy monsters are at?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the level and XP reward of mobs in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66886/how-do-i-determine-the-level-and-xp-reward-of-mobs-in-diablo-iii)

I saw [this awesome explanation](http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/diablo-3-experience-points-explained.html) of how much EXP is gained relative to you and the monsters' levels. The problem is, I have no clue what level the enemy monster is. How do I know if I'm fighting monsters 10 levels above me or 20 below me.